# Variable change not recognized

Tags: java, variables

I'm quite new to java, but have run into a problem I don't understand. I want a jbutton to show one window and hide another. I have done this with an endless loop listening for a variable change when the jbutton is pressed.

```
private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) { //Jbutton in question
      NewJFrame frame = new NewJFrame(); //another JFrame from which I created the public variable(Visible)
      frame.Visible = false;
} 

    while (always == true) {     **//code in main method to test variable change** 
        if (frame1.Visible == true) {
            frame1.show();
            frame2.hide();
        }
        else {
            frame1.show();
            frame2.hide();
        }
```

Interrestingly, this works when I do the same with a button inside the JFrame of which the public variable (Visible) is created, AKA: the [if] part, but the else does not execute.

Is there something I can do to get the Main method to rocognize this variable change?

Comment: Why not just have the button click event toggle each frames visibility?  Having a `while (true)` loop is unnecessary and thrashing the CPU

Comment: I agree, you should just listen for the click event. There is no justification for the loop, and when it is necessary to use a loop, don't forget to break out of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have a logic error.

You say `if(frame1.Visible)` then `frame1.show()`.  But `frame1` is already visible!  It doesn't look like you ever hide it.

My guess would be your intentions were instead to have:

```
    if (frame1.Visible == true) {
        frame1.hide();
        frame2.show();
    }
```

Also, as a side note, you don't have to use `== true` or `== false` with booleans.  They will be evaluated in the conditional automatically as whichever value they represent.

Comment: @MarthinusBosman Haha, don't!  Everyone starts somewhere, and even the most veteran programmers make mistakes, look back at their code, and wonder "...What was I thinking?"